# Firebase not accepting token during Travis CI Run

Tags: firebase, environment-variables, travis-ci

I am trying to deploy my application using Travis CI and a Firebase deploy to run tests against. I generated the Firebase token and stored it in Travis as `FIREBASE_TOKEN` and have used this token to deploy it locally, however when I try in Travis, it fails with a 401 error.

[image: Environment Variable Saved in Travis]

```
after_success:
  - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive
```

```
Error: HTTP Error: 401, Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

However if I run the command locally, **with the exact same token**, it works just fine and deploys

The full `.travis.yml` file is:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
 - "12.6"
before_install:
 - rvm install 2.6.3
install:
 - gem install bundler
 - npm install
before_script:
 - bundle install
 - npm install -g firebase-tools
script:
 - bundle exec jekyll build
after_success:
 - firebase deploy --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive
```

Comment: can you share your circle.yaml file?

Comment: @andresmijares Added the travis.yml file to the question

Comment: I have a very similar config, my only difference is that I don't use the --token flag, making sure $FIREBASE_TOKEN is set is good enough, take a look and let me know